# Jenkins - extended E-mail notification - Fill default recipents with user list from jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, user-management

I am trying to setup e-mail notifications in jenkins, which should sent an e-mail to the developer who crashed the build.

Therefore I filled the `default Recipents` list by hand for some developers:

[image: User list manually added]

What I want is, that I don't have to manually add every e-mail address in this list, instead getting the e-mail list from the registered users in jenkins. When a user is removed, he should removed from the list and the same, when a new user is added.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't need the emails in the default recipents list. When i specify the correct repository, jenkins finds the correct e-mails out on its own